# submit a form within leaflet popup does not return result

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, leaflet

I am trying to send a form within a leaflet popup in my database with submit button, however there is no reaction if I click on the submit button for each marker, which I created with the Leaflet.draw plugin. Here is my code:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e){
    var type = e.layerType;
    layer = e.layer;
    var y = layer.getLatLng().lat;
    var x = layer.getLatLng().lng;

var Marker = drawnItems.addLayer(layer);

Marker.on('click', function (e){
  var popupContent =  '<form role="form" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" class ="form-horizontal" >'+ 
 '<div class="form-group">'+
'<label>Adresse <input type="text" name="text" id="text"></label>' +     '<br/>'  +
'<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="submit">Add</button>'+ 
'</div>' +
'</form>';

 var popup = L.popup()
  .setLatLng(e.latlng)
  .setContent(popupContent)
  .openOn(map);

 map.addLayer(layer);

 });

$('#form').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("submit worked!");
  var text = $('#text').val();

   });

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute `$('#form').submit()` the `<form id="form">` is not a node yet (you have only defined the HTML code as string).

Therefore jQuery will not be able to attach an event listener on it.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fbfy7sLy/

You have 2 easy workarounds:

- Attach your event listener *after* the node is created. I.e. in your case after the popup is added onto the map.
- Use *event delegation* so that even if the node is created later on, the listener is attached to a parent node already existing, but it works *as if* the listener were attached to the new node. E.g. you can use jQuery's [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```js
$(document).delegate('#form', 'click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // your stuff
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fbfy7sLy/1/